# Convert emoji to html hex with java library & Lucee

Tags: java, jar, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I'm trying to convert a emoji into html hexadecimal using this java library: https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java
*(taken from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vdurmont/emoji-java/3.1.0 )*

```
emojiUtils = createObject( "java", "com.vdurmont.emoji.Emoji", "/componenti/jar/emoji-java-3.1.0.jar" );

var myTitle = privateFunctionGetTitle(); // for example

var cleanTitle = emojiUtils.getHtmlHexidecimal(myTitle);
```

**but I get this error:** `No matching Method for getHtmlHexidecimal(string) found for com.vdurmont.emoji.Emoji`

I try *(for debug)* `writeDump(emojiUtils);`
[image: emojiUtils debug]

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I also tried this:

```
EmojiParser = createObject( "java", "com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiParser", "/componenti/jar/emoji-java-3.1.0.jar" ); 

writeDump(EmojiParser.parseToHtmlDecimal(titoloPagina));
```

but I get:

> ```
> lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: Could not initialize class 
>     com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiManager
> ...
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>     Could not initialize class com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiManager 
> ... 80 more
> ```

**StackTrace**: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivanionut/8f4e6e356c0b2c8474d21c52d796df3a/raw/5b23ba3ff5f7c930381a8109ea43e29042cc7813/StackTrace

Comment: try `emojiUtils.init(myTitle).getHtmlHexidecimal()`, `getHtmlHexidecimal` does not take any arguments.

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan: `No matching Constructor for com.vdurmont.emoji.Emoji(string) found`

Comment: You need to work from a Java sample. This example has no init - nothing that even takes an argument execmpt for getUnicode().

Comment: @MarkAKruger: ok, I'm sorry, but I am very ignorant with java objects.  How should I do in this situation?

Comment: @Ivan - The constructor is protected, so you cannot instantiate it outside the package. If you are trying to replace, a skim of the project suggests you should be using use the EmojiParser class instead. Try the static method `EmojiParser.parseToHtmlDecimal(string)` instead, which: *..replace[s] all the emoji's unicodes found in a string by their html representation*.

Comment: @Leigh 
`EmojiParser = createObject( "java", "com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiParser", "/componenti/jar/emoji-java-3.1.0.jar" );
writeDump(EmojiParser.parseToHtmlDecimal(titoloPagina));`

but I get:

`Could not initialize class com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiManager`

Comment: Not sure why.  That class loads fine under CF11, using the same jar.  Can you update your question with the full stack trace message? Also, check the logs for more details about that error.

Comment: @Leigh I added the StackTrace

Comment: The library has a dependency on org.json. Try loading that jar too. Version 20140107 in repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107

Answer (score 2):

As some people suggested, you're not using the library like I was planning to when I wrote it :)

You should never have to "create an object". If you want to get the hexadecimal string for an emoji, you should follow the documentation and do:

```
Emoji wink = EmojiManager.getForAlias("wink");
String hexa = wink.getHexidecimal(); // Yes, "hexidecimal"... It's a typo that is fixed if you update to 3.1.1
```

If you want to change all unicode emojis in a string to their hexadecimal representation, you should do:

```
String str = "An awesome string with a few emojis!";
String resultHexadecimal = EmojiParser.parseToHtmlHexadecimal(str);
System.out.println(resultHexadecimal);
// Prints:
// "An &#x1f600;awesome &#x1f603;string with a few &#x1f609;emojis!"
```

On the "integration" side, you're going to have to resolve the dependencies and path yourself:

- this line must point to the right file: https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdurmont/emoji/EmojiManager.java#L18
- you also have to get the right jar for `org.json`

If you used a package manager (Maven, Gradle..), it would be easier IMO.

Comment: Nice to get a response directly from the source :) RE: *...this line must point to the right file*. They are using the [pre-compiled jar from mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vdurmont/emoji-java/3.1.0) which contains "emojis.json" in the root folder. If PATH is not changed, does getResourceAsStream load that file by default?

Comment: Yep, it *should* work. No guarantee though :D I strongly suggest to use a package manager instead of importing the jars yourself. By doing this, you'll avoid an entire category of bugs :)

Comment: Yeah, as always there are variables in play, so I know ... "it depends" :)  Ivan's actually using the jar in a custom servlet. The jar gets loaded via a feature that uses a dynamic class loader.  Some of the methods are working from the servlet, but not `EmojiParser.parseToHtmlHexadecimal` so far. In the servlet it returns the original string for me. Though I suspect is something to do with the environment, so I will have to try the same in Eclipse and see if I can figure out what is different.

Comment: Ah, figured out the problem.  The emjoi.json was not being loaded correctly ([see my comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36969323/104223)).

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for comments)

One addition to [Vicent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36942766/104223). While the example above worked fine from Eclipse, strangely it did not work for me using CF11 or Lucee 4.5. Turns out the reason was my JVM was using the default encoding Cp1252. So when [EmojiLoader.java loaded the "emojis.json" file stream on line 52](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdurmont/emoji/EmojiLoader.java#L52), the contents were not being interpreted correctly.

To fix the issue, you can either:

1. Change the JVM default encoding to UTF-8, ie `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` .. OR
2. Change the EmojiLoader.java source to specify UTF-8 encoding and rebuild the jar:

   ```
   // In v3.1.0, change line #52 from:
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

   // ... to this instead
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
   ```

After making one of those changes, it should work fine from CF/Lucee. Note, as mentioned above, v3.1.0 of the library has a dependency on org.json v20140107. See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107

**Lucee Example:**

```
jarPaths = ["C:\path\your-emoji-jar.jar", "C:\path\json-20140107.jar"];
EmojiParser = createObject( "java", "com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiParser", jarPaths); 
str = "An awesome string with a few emojis!";
result = EmojiParser.parseToHtmlHexadecimal(str);
writeDump(result);
```